# User-defined network on docker 19.03 with CentOS 8 with not working

Tags: docker, centos8

Environment Setup:

```
OS: CentOS Linux release 8.2.2004 (Core)
Docker Version: 
 Client: Docker Engine - Community
    Version:           19.03.11
    API version:       1.40
    Go version:        go1.13.10
    Git commit:        42e35e61f3
    Built:             Mon Jun  1 09:13:48 2020
    OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
    Experimental:      false

  Server: Docker Engine - Community
    Engine:
      Version:          19.03.11
      API version:      1.40 (minimum version 1.12)
      Go version:       go1.13.10
      Git commit:       42e35e61f3
      Built:            Mon Jun  1 09:12:26 2020
      OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
      Experimental:     false
      containerd:
         Version:          1.2.6
         GitCommit:        894b81a4b802e4eb2a91d1ce216b8817763c29fb
      runc:
         Version:          1.0.0-rc8
         GitCommit:        425e105d5a03fabd737a126ad93d62a9eeede87f
      docker-init:
         Version:          0.18.0
         GitCommit:        fec3683
```

The Linux Machine is connected to corporate network behind firewall. Following are details:

1. /etc/hosts

   ```
     127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
     ::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
   ```
2. /etc/resolv.conf

   ```
     # Generated by NetworkManager
       search subdomain.domain.com
       nameserver 13.108.0.11
       nameserver 13.108.11.16
   ```
3. Created user-defined bridge network:

   ```
    $ docker network create mynetwork
    $ docker network ls
    NETWORK ID          NAME                DRIVER              SCOPE
    05400c341d1d        bridge              bridge              local
    fb4e364ad31b        host                host                local
    835f9d99e610        none                null                local
    7d8fc26d3632        mynetwork           bridge              local
   ```
4. Created two container on mynetwork:

   ```
   $ docker container run --name search1 --network mynetwork --network-alias search --detach elasticsearch:2
   ```

   and

   ```
   $ docker container run --name search2 --network mynetwork --network-alias search --detach elasticsearch:2
   ```
5. DNS round robin check:

   `$ docker container run --rm -it --network mynetowrk alpine nslookup search`

   **Output**:

   ```
    Server:         127.0.0.11
    Address:        127.0.0.11:53
    ** server can't find search.subdomain.domain.com: NXDOMAIN
    ** server can't find search.subdomain.domain.com: NXDOMAIN
   ```
6. Container /etc/resolv.conf

   ```
    $ docker container run --rm -it --network mynetwork alpine cat /etc/resolv.conf
   ```

   **Output**:

   ```
    search subdomain.domain.com
    nameserver 127.0.0.11
    options ndots:0
   ```
7. Docker User Defined Network Details:

   `$ docker network inspect -v mynetwork`

**Output**:

> ```
>      [
>          {
>              "Name": "mynetwork",
>              "Id": "7d8fc26d36323cf9ba47dbb272bf4ad15113d6b26a26fbf6c82cc1d866b480c0",
>              "Created": "2020-06-18T09:54:12.37673638+05:30",
>              "Scope": "local",
>              "Driver": "bridge",
>              "EnableIPv6": false,
>              "IPAM": {
>                  "Driver": "default",
>                  "Options": {},
>                  "Config": [
>                      {
>                          "Subnet": "172.19.0.0/16",
>                          "Gateway": "172.19.0.1"
>                      }
>                  ]
>              },
>              "Internal": false,
>              "Attachable": true,
>              "Ingress": false,
>              "ConfigFrom": {
>                  "Network": ""
>              },
>              "ConfigOnly": false,
>              "Containers": {
>              "ec1cacb437926b5c6bb5693ab9c0afa6f8bc2764d5e15a5e15d9d5709346c1e5": {
>                      "Name": "search1",
>                      "EndpointID": "2c7420176adbce496e4c033416d98c290cf74dcc1e68568d7160b45cefd8d1db",
>                      "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:13:00:02",
>                      "IPv4Address": "172.19.0.2/16",
>                      "IPv6Address": ""
>                  },
>             "f7cf532aa71df9cefaf5575ff27d4a2f4525f7674a479989d5b96f281282b6db": {
>                      "Name": "search2",
>                      "EndpointID": "d641f94dfc1d898d7d8ec667b4389d4ff6a0d53be3454a89f77b24b0bd04a663",
>                      "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:13:00:03",
>                      "IPv4Address": "172.19.0.3/16",
>                      "IPv6Address": ""
>                  }
>              },
>              "Options": {},
>              "Labels": {}
>         }
> ]
> ```

Questions:

- Why docker is using host search domain in user defined  docker network?
- Why the network alias is not resolvable?
- Is it something to do with CentOS 8.2 version?
- How to fix it ? or How to make it working?

Thanks

Comment: Does it work if you use Debian instead of Alpine for the nslookup container. There are also several typos in the commands, and the same container name in both, network misspelled, missing spaces. Is that just in the question, do you have typos in the commands you ran? Please provide the `docker network inspect -v mynetwork` output too.

Comment: On Debian: Server:         127.0.0.11
Address:        127.0.0.11#53

Non-authoritative answer:
*** Can't find search: No answer

Comment: I have attached the output of: ```docker network inspect -v mynetwork``` in the question.

Comment: I have checked on my machine. Reformatted twice same error. Ping command gives: ```ping: bad address 'search'```

Comment: I think the DNS problem you are facing @Amarjeet Sharma is because of the following -- https://phoenixnap.com/kb/how-to-install-docker-on-centos-8 .

Is your problem resolved ? I am facing similar DNS resolution issue on CentOS 8 even after disabling firewalld

Answer (score 1):

`sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-masquerade`